# How to know where a surface concaves up or not.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to know if there is a way to find where a surface concaves up.

In a calculus course, I learned that if you want to know the concavity of a several variable real valued function, you should set a direction and find a second derivative of the given direction.

But,, I think it gives us only restricted information(local information) about the graph of a function. If I want to know whether the function concaves up or not, I might have to find the second derivatives of all directions and check if they are all positive, but it seems almost impossible without computer.

I understand the way to find where a graph concaves up , given a direction. But isn’t there a way to find a global property of a graph, i.e. without thinking of direction.

I’m so sorry if my questions isn’t clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $C^2$ function $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on a convex domain $U$ is convex if and only if its Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite for all points in $U$. Similar conditions exist for concavity. Check [here](http://www.rmi.ge/~kade/LecturesT.Kadeishvili/MathEconomics/Term4/Week6Concave.pdf) for more information (more precisely, look at page $5$).

I think $U$ doesn't necessarily have to be a convex set, maybe only being a star-shaped set suffices for this theorem to work.

If you want to look at the behavior of $f$ at a certain $x$, take a small enough neighborhood $x\in V \subset U$ and consider convexity or concavity there.

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot! I didn’t know Hessian is related to this subject. I think it is in the later chapter of my book. I didn’t go that further yet! I will read the link you gave and read my textbook too. Thank you so much :). But what do you mean by star-shaped? You mean the region of a domain looks like a star?

Comment: @ylh0501  you're welcome. I'm glad it helped. A star-shaped domain $U$ is a domain where there exists a special point $x_*$ such that the line passing through $x_*$ and any other point $x \in U$ will lie completely inside $U$. It's weaker than the concept of a set being convex. Every convex set is star-shaped, but not every star-shaped set is convex. Namely, the shape of a star is star-shaped but not convex.

Comment: Oh, it is interesting :) A star shaped requires only one point to satisfy the given condition, while a convex set requires all of the points to do. Thanks for your explaining! I definitely should study about it more. :)

Comment: Hmm maybe it’s interesting to find a star shaped set where one point satisfies the condition, but the other points don’t. Oh! Maybe ‘+’ is such a star shaped set!

Comment: @ylh0501 You're right. '+' and '*' are star-shaped but obviously not convex.

Comment: Yes! Thank you :):)